# How to include another table to view its data in Views in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have this code -

```
var add = (from h in db.Hotels
           where h.Address.Contains(hotels.Address)
           select h).Take(2);

ViewBag.Related = add;
```

Now, in the View, I want to display the images, so I'm using this code -

```
<img src="~/img/@item.FirstOrDefault().Image" />
```

This is giving me this error -

```
'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Hotels_D1EE6FD2E11BD1D9436F26FEA6336CFE76F33C59111E2ABC7C1BBE456FF61C23' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'
```

I've tried using 'joins' also but same error occurs. Please help me out in this! :(

My Hotels class -

```
public class Hotels
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string PinCode { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FilledBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        //public int ImageId { get; set; }

        public int TotalRooms { get; set; }

        public bool Available { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection <Rooms> Rooms { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection <Images> Images { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ameneties> Ameneties { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection <Bookings> Bookings { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<NearByLocations> Nearby { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ratings> Ratings { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RoomType> RoomTypes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomerReviews> Reviews { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<HotelRules> HotelRules { get; set; }

    }
```

My Images class -

```
public class Images
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }

        public int? HotelId { get; set; }
        public virtual Hotels Hotels { get; set; }

        //public ICollection<Hotels> Hotels { get; set; }

    }
```

I have used this type of collections...

This is my Details View Controller code -

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {

            IEnumerable<Images> galleries = (from gallery in db.Images
                                             where gallery.Hotels.Id == id
                                                  select gallery);
            ViewBag.Images = galleries;
            ViewBag.ImgCount = galleries.Count();

            IEnumerable<Ameneties> ameneties = (from a in db.Ameneties
                                                where a.Hotels.Id == id
                                                select a);
            ViewBag.Ameneties = ameneties;

            IQueryable<Rooms> rooms = (from room in db.Rooms
                                       where room.Hotels.Id == id
                                       select room);

            var ratings = (from rating in db.Ratings
                           where rating.Hotels.Id == id
                           select rating.Points);

            ViewBag.Ratings = ratings;

            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Hotels hotels = db.Hotels.Find(id);
            if (hotels == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var add = db.Hotels.Include("Images").Where(h => h.Address.Contains(hotels.Address))
        .Select(h => h)
        .Take(2)
        .ToList();

            var model = new MyViewModel { Hotels = add };


            ViewBag.Reviews = hotels.Reviews;

            ViewBag.Ratings = hotels.Ratings;

            ViewBag.NearBy = hotels.Nearby;

            ViewBag.RoomTypes = hotels.RoomTypes;

            ViewBag.Rules = hotels.HotelRules;

            return View(hotels);

        }
```

Comment: How did you get `item`? Could you show your view?

Comment: here - 

 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Related){
                                    <img src="~/img/@item.FirstOrDefault().Image" />
}

Comment: `item` is not a collection; you could use `item.Image`. Otherwise, what is the relationship between Hotels and Image.

Comment: I have used foreign key relation. Foreign key is in the 'Images' table with 'Hotel'

Comment: Could you show both `Hotel` class and `Image` class?

Comment: while using item.Image I'm getting this error

Comment: public class Hotels
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public bool Available { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection <Rooms> Rooms { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection <Images> Images { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `ToList()` at the end of the query?

```
var add = (from h in db.Hotels
           where h.Address.Contains(hotels.Address)
           select h).Take(2)
           .ToList();

ViewBag.Related = add;
```

Then you could call `item.Images.FirstOrDefault()?.Image`.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Related)
{ 
   <img src="~/img/@item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Image" /> 
}
```

If it still doesn't work, you will need to explicitly load `Image` when you query `Hotel`. For example,

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var add = db.Hotels
        .Include("Images")
        .Where(h => h.Address.Contains(hotels.Address))
        .Select(h => h)
        .Take(2)
        .ToList();

    var model = new MyViewModel { Hotels = add };
    return View(model);
}
```

### View

```
@model YourNameSpace.Models.MyViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Hotels)
{ 
    <img src="~/img/@item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Image" /> 
}
```

### Model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Hotels> Hotels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've used but this got this error -

'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Hotels_D1EE6FD2E11BD1D9436F26FEA6336CFE76F33C59111E2ABC7C1BBE456FF61C23' does not contain a definition for 'Image'

Comment: Could you ensure you have `....ToList();` and you access image like this `item.Images.FirstOrDefault()?.Image`?

Comment: Could you pass strongly typed ViewModel from action method to view instead of ViewBag?

Comment: How to do that? I'm new this MVC :(

Comment: getting error while using `MyViewModel` and `IActionResult`

Comment: You gotta stop using ViewBag. Create properties inside ViewModel. Then you return `View(model);` instead of `View(hotel);`

Comment: but I'm using this to get the details of a Hotel, how do i pass the id using this model?